# Defer render blocking CSS bundles in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, seo

When I use [Google Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

it says that my CSS is render-blocking and hence slowing down the initial loading of the page.  In previous projects I have added CSS dynamically with Javascript and this worked well to defer the loading.  So what is the best way to prevent render-blocking while still using bundles?

In bundle.config I have:

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"
                  ));
```

In _Layout.cshtml

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

Comment: You should be able to use @Styles.Url("~/Content/css")  - which will create the url to the bundle only, not the entire html element

Comment: Any css(bundle has nothing to do with it) referenced in normal way is render-blocking, and that's in purpose. If you site's main css doesn't establish render-blocking, your client will first see a breaking version of text-only webpage, and then see the flip of css getting applied, which is usually not the ideal user experience

Comment: hmm I personally think it is a better experience to see the page evolving rather than seeing nothing.  Google seems to share the same view with their Page Insights algorithm.

Comment: `Simple page -> Complete page` evolving is a different story to `Plain text -> Complete page`, usually only the first one is suggested, but also more complicated. Having 100% of your main css async load is not a great idea IMO, but of course you can do that for getting a better metric. It's already off topic for your question so I will stop here. But I just want to remind that you are creating webpage for user experience, not page load metric.

Comment: Yeah, what you say is along the same lines as what [Google recommends](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery#dataURI).  Basically render the important CSS first (to make the site look decent while the rest is loading)...then defer the remaining CSS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a solution myself by using the following HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function load_css_async(filename) {


        var cb = function () {
            var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
            l.href = filename;
            var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
        };
        var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
            webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
        if (raf) raf(cb);
        else window.addEventListener('load', cb);


    }

</script>


@Styles.RenderFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\">load_css_async('{0}')</script>", "~/Content/css")
```

And that has given me 100 / 100 in Page Insights :)